# Wso2 User getting unauthorized

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using Identity server 5.2.0 and api manager 2.0.0. I have implemented a method to use refresh token to get the new access token for a user if the token has expired. But after implementing this some of the users will be unauthorized. When the user tries to login, token and scopes will be returned correctly but when calling the an api with the token, the user is unauthorized. Deleting and adding the user with same username also does not solve the issue. Is there any setting that blocks a user that may cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the application in APIM is subscribed to the API you're trying to invoke? If not, you need to do that.

Comment: yes the application is subscribed and everything works fine as long as i don't call the refresh token API. Is there any setting or configuration that might cause this?

Comment: If the scopes are correctly returned, the token should work. Do you see any errors in the logs, when invoking the API?

Comment: yes there are errors in the wso2 logs.

ERROR OAuth2TokenEndpoint Error while creating the Carbon OAuth token request
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Invalid grant_type parameter value', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}

Comment: I get this error and then the system loops and creates the same error and the user becomes invalid. This is not happening in all cases. It only happens once in a while. If the refresh token sent is expired will it cause this issue? is there any way to recover users that become invalid like this?